# MongoDB query doesn't behave as expected with nested elements

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to return results which match a value and also match on child properties. So I want to return say results which match the month and then match a range of values. However I find even the simple search, doesn't seem to return any results which I would expect.

Using pymongo my query is:

```
month = 2
results = db.master.find({"months": str(month)})
```

This should surely return all matching documents for the correct month. However I get no records returns for month=2

My data is stored in MDB as:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "568d0bebc1bed847da7a2e6f"
    },
    "months": {
        "2": {
            "std_rank": 0.11338862902393358,
            "rank_gain": 0.6183933826187626,
            "gain": 0.9618213660245183,
            "std": 0.021891473641317716
        },
    "months": {
        "3": {
            "std_rank": 0.11338862902393358,
            "rank_gain": 0.6183933826187626,
            "gain": 0.9618213660245183,
            "std": 0.021891473641317716
        },   
    },
    "code": "VU"
}
```

One suggested answer works for filtering correct month, now the question is how to apply a filter to its child elements. For example:

```
results = db.master.find({}, {"_id": 0, "months." + str(month): 1, "months.std_rank": {"$lte": max_std_rank, "$gte": min_std_rank} } )
```

I get the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue >1 field in obj: { $gte: 0.0, $lte: 1.0 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for projection as `db.master.find({}, { "_id": 0, "months.2": 1 })`

Comment: I don't work in python but you need to concat months with 2
may be something like 
`month = 2;

db.master.find({"months"+str(month): {$exists: true}})`

Comment: @chridam That helps narrow the fields to month = 2 for example, next, how does one then filter the child values.

Comment: Try `results = db.master.find({ "months." + str(month) + ".std_rank": {"$lte": max_std_rank, "$gte": min_std_rank } }, { "_id": 0, "months." + str(month): 1 } )`

Comment: @chridam Thanks - very useful, MDB feels so hacky at time. How about creating an answer for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query

```
results = db.master.find({ "months." + str(month) + ".std_rank": {"$lte": max_std_rank, "$gte": min_std_rank } }, { "_id": 0, "months." + str(month): 1 } )
```

which uses projection to return only the document matching the given month key.